# Does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k\sqrt{\vphantom{} k+1}}$ converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Does the following series converge? $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k\sqrt{\vphantom{|} k+1}}$$

I tried using the ratio test and the comparison test but I wasn't able to solve this.

I think I should try manipulating the denominator to use comparison test but I can't figure out how?

Comment: Do you know p-test?

Comment: Correct. You should manipulate the denominator.

Comment: @ThePortakal no, I'm not familiar with that

Comment: @112358 The p-test says $\sum \frac{1}{k^p}$ converge if $p>1$, and diverge if $p \leq 1$

Comment: @snulty: Why is there a `\vphantom` there?

Comment: @AsafKaragila you can remove it if you want, the square root symbol was annoying me, it just didn't look right on my laptop screen. As in the top horizontal line wasn't lining up with the top of the vertical line

Comment: @snulty: That's a bug to report, not something to hack around. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24945/mathjax-2-7-beta

Comment: @AsafKaragila I didn't realise. I'll have to wait until I'm back on my desktop to remove the vphantom, take a screenshot etc in that case.

Comment: @snulty: Now you know. And knowing is half the battle!

Answer (score 6):

Note that $\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k+1}} < \frac{1}{k \sqrt{k}} = k^{-1.5}$.

Hence, by the comparison test, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k+1}} < \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1.5} < \infty$ for all $n$. Hence $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k+1}}$ converges, and in fact it is somewhere  close to $2.04288$ by Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Mathematica says that the sum is approximately $2.18400947\dots$

Comment: I didn't take enough terms. Anyway, it's convergent.

Comment: perhaps a typo: $\frac1{k\sqrt{k}}\color{#C00000}{=}k^{-1.5}$

Comment: @robjohn Thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: $\sum_n n^{-p}$ converges for $p>1$ by the Cauchy Condensation Test.

Comment: @user254665 Thank you for the note.

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation of robjonh's fine answer through creative telescoping.
We may check in advance that for every $k\geq 1$ the inequality
$$ \frac{1}{k\sqrt{k+1}}\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{k-\frac{1}{5}}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{k+\frac{4}{5}}}\tag{1}$$
holds, hence it follows that:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k+1}}\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{5}}}=\color{red}{\sqrt{5}}. \tag{2}$$

Comment: This gets closer to the actual sum of $2.18400947\dots$ than $1+\sqrt2$, which I got. (+1) What's a good way to verify $(1)$?

Comment: @robjohn: I "squared till death" and computed a discriminant, but there are probably slicker ways.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the terms in groups of $2^n$,
$$\frac1{\sqrt2}<1,\\
\frac1{2\sqrt3}+\frac1{3\sqrt4}<\frac1{\sqrt2},\\
\frac1{4\sqrt5}+\frac1{5\sqrt6}+\frac1{6\sqrt7}+\frac2{7\sqrt8}<\frac1{\sqrt{2^2}},\\
\frac1{8\sqrt9}+\frac1{9\sqrt{10}}+\frac1{10\sqrt{11}}+\frac2{11\sqrt{12}}+\frac1{12\sqrt{13}}+\frac1{13\sqrt{14}}+\frac1{14\sqrt{15}}+\frac2{15\sqrt{16}}<\frac1{\sqrt{2^3}},\\\cdots
$$
and the sum is bounded by a geometriec series of common factor $1/\sqrt2$.

---

The property will remain true replacing the square root by any positive power. (And by a similar lower bound you will show divergence for any non-positive power.)

Comment: See the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

Answer (score 1):

For $k\ge1$, $\sqrt{k+1}\le\sqrt{2k}$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sqrt{k}}-\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}
&=\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k}\sqrt{k+1}}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{k}\sqrt{k+1}\left(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}\right)}\\
&\ge\frac1{\left(1+\sqrt2\right)k\sqrt{k+1}}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k\sqrt{k+1}}
&\le\left(1+\sqrt2\right)\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{\sqrt{k}}-\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\right)\\
&=1+\sqrt2
\end{align}
$$
So the series converges.

---

Using $8$ terms of the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula applied to $14$ terms of the Taylor Series for $\frac1{k\sqrt{k+1}}$ and comparing to $1000$ terms of the actual sum gives
$$
\sum_{k}\frac1{k\sqrt{k+1}}=2.18400947026785195289473415785294907
$$

Answer (score -1):

Using the fact that square root of x+1 > square root of (x), for x>0 and p test, it converges

Comment: You think that $\sum\frac1{n\log n}$ converges?

Comment: @TravisJ Yeah, a silent edit replaced `ln` by `sqrt`... Gotta love it. (Note: This also copies astonvilla's answer.)